# Circular dependency with react useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) react provider. The provider ultimately exposes a value read over Bluetooth.

The provider also attempts to reconnect to the BLE device when the connection is lost.

Here's a simplified version of the provider:

```
const BLEDataContext = createContext<{
  bleData: number | null;
}>({
  bleData: null
});

export const BLEDataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [bleData, setBleData] = useState(null as number | null);

  const connect = useCallback(async () => {
    const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ 
      filters, 
      optionalServices, 
    });
    // [...]
    device.addEventListener('gattserverdisconnected', onDisconnected);
    return device;
  }, [onDisconnected, /* more deps */]);

  const onDisconnected = useCallback((event: any) => {
    // [...]
    if (someCondition) {
      connect();
    }
  }, [connect, /* more deps */]);

  return (
    <BLEDataContext.Provider value={{ bleData }}>
      {children}
    </BLEDataContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

How can I handle the circular dependency between these functions?

I've tried inlining the `onDisconnected` handler inside the `connect` method, but that just moves the problem.

I've also tried removing the `useCallback` around `onDisconnected`, but eslint warns me:

> The 'onDisconnected' function makes the dependencies of useCallback Hook (at line 87) change on every render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `connect` function store the `device` in a state. Create another `useEffect` blocks that react to `device` state changes (or unmount), and removes the listener from the previous device, and sets it on the new device:

```
const BLEDataContext = createContext<{
  bleData: number | null;
}>({
  bleData: null
});

export const BLEDataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [device, setDevice] = useState<BluetoothDevice | null>();
  const [bleData, setBleData] = useState<number | null>(null);
  
  const connect = useCallback(async () => {
    const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ 
      filters, 
      optionalServices, 
    });
    // [...]

    setDevice(device);
  }, [/* more deps */]);
  
  // connect the device on mount or when the connect's function deps change
  useEffect(() => { 
    connect();
  }, [connect]);
  
  // when device changes remove previous gattserverdisconnected event handler
  // and set gattserverdisconnected event handler on new device
  useEffect(() => {
    const onDisconnected = (event: any) => {
      // [...]
      if (someCondition) {
        connect();
      }
    };
    
    device?.addEventListener('gattserverdisconnected', onDisconnected);

    return () => {
      device?.removeEventListener('gattserverdisconnected', onDisconnected);
    };
  }, [connect, device, /* more deps */]);

  return (
    <BLEDataContext.Provider value={{ bleData }}>
      {children}
    </BLEDataContext.Provider>
  );
}
```